# Как создавать объекты в UI canvas`e в unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Короче, я хочу создать вот что. В начале уровня я хочу добавить уведомление которое будет начинать волны, я пытаюсь его призвать через Instantiate и префаб, но я не знаю как можно его создать в canvas`e что бы уведомление всегда было с камерой. Может есть какие-то лучшие способы, был бы рад если бы вы подсказали

Comment: Зайди в документацию метода Instantiate, там найдешь перегрузку, куда можно передать трансформ родителя. Передавай в этот метод трансформ канваса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У метода **Instantiate** есть перегрузка, позволяющая **указывать родителя** создаваемого обьект.

```
public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Transform parent);
```

Вам нужно получить Transform канваса и использовать метод сверху.

```
public static Object Instantiate(Object ПРЕФАБ, Transform ТРАНСФОРМ КАНВАСА);
```